# Python Flask WTForms custom FloatField only works for one form class

Tags: python, wtforms

I have multiple forms where I use my custom FloatField (MyFloatField).

I made a custom FloatField so I can replace the `,` if a users enters a float with a `,` - 20,00 becomes 20.00.

Here is my custom FloatField:

```
class MyFloatField(FloatField):
    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            try:
                self.data = float(valuelist[0].replace(',', '.'))
            except ValueError:
                self.data = None
                raise ValueError(self.gettext('Kein valider Wert'))
```

I have a form where it works fine.

```
class ZimmerForm(Form): 
    preis = MyFloatField('Preis pro Person', validators=[Optional()])   
    preis_doppelzimmer = MyFloatField('Preis pro Person', validators=[Optional()])
    preis_mehrbettzimmer = MyFloatField('Preis pro Person', validators=[Optional()])    
    preis_wohunung = MyFloatField('Preis pro Person', validators=[Optional()])
```

I also have some other forms where I need the same behaviour, but it seems that it does not work. I am getting a `DataError`:

```
DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) FEHLER:  ungÃ¼ltige Eingabesyntax fÃ¼r Typ double precision: â12,90â
LINE 1: ...zimmer SET anzahl_zimmer='2', personen='2', preis='12,90' WH...
                                                             ^
 [SQL: 'UPDATE einzelzimmer SET anzahl_zimmer=%(anzahl_zimmer)s, personen=%(personen)s, preis=%(preis)s WHERE einzelzimmer.id = %(einzelzimmer_id)s'] [parameters: {'einzelzimmer_id': 50, 'anzahl_zimmer': u'2', 'personen': u'2', 'preis': u'12,90'}]
```

As far as I understand the float with the `,` is not replaced.

Here are my other forms:

```
class EditZimmerForm_Einzel(Form):
    preis = MyFloatField('Preis pro Person', validators=[DataRequired(message="Geben Sie an wie teuer eine Nacht pro Person ist")])

class EditZimmerForm_Doppel(Form):
    preis_doppelz = MyFloatField('Preis pro Person', validators=[DataRequired(message="Geben Sie an wie teuer eine Nacht pro Person ist")])

class EditZimmerForm_Mehrbett(Form):
    preis_mehrbettz = MyFloatField('Preis pro Person', validators=[DataRequired(message="Geben Sie an wie teuer eine Nacht pro Person ist")])

class EditZimmerForm_Wohnung(Form):
    preis_wohnungz = MyFloatField('Preis pro Person', validators=[DataRequired(message="Geben Sie an wie teuer eine Nacht pro Person ist")])
```

**EDIT**

The only difference between these forms is that, the first one where it works has no value. The user enters a value.

The forms where it does not work are for editing. That means there is already a value.

Comment: In cases where it does not work, does your code even enter the process_formdata function?

Comment: yes is does enter it even prints the correct values

Answer (score 2):

Class MyFloatField is still a FloatField.  The string containing a comma isn't a valid float so it'll cause an error.

I suggest that you instead use a normal `StringField` and use a custom validator to ensure the input meets your requirements.  Something like this in `forms.py`:

```
def currency(form, field):
    try:
        Decimal(field.data)
    except:
        raise StopValidation('Value must be in decimal format')
    if Decimal(field.data) < 0:
        raise StopValidation('Value must be greater than zero')

class ZimmerForm(Form):
    preis = StringField('Preis pro Person', [currency, Optional()])
```